# Como ajustar la escala de un gráfico ternario (triangular)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy intentando hacer un gráfico triangular a partir de los valores de beta diversidad, de manera que me quede en uno un gráfico triangular para una familia con puntos de colores para cada columna y en otro lo mismo para la otra familia. Ya sea usando la función ggplot, ggtern u otra. Pudieran ayudarme por favor o darme alguna sugerencia. Gracias de antemano

Adjunto parte de la matriz

```
Regiones    βjtu    βjne    βjac
I-II        0.85    0.05    0.90
I-III       0.78    0.02    0.80
I-IV        0.44    0.24    0.68
I-V         0.77    0.08    0.85
I-VI        0.85    0.02    0.85
I-VII       0.85    0.09    0.81
II-III      0.88    0.03    0.91
II-IV       0.51    0.32    0.85
II-V        0.88    0.04    0.89
II-VI       0.88    0.02    0.91
II-VII      0.91    0.02    0.91
```

Y el código que estoy probando

```
library (vegan)
library (betapart)
library (ggtern) 
## Raw data and plotting data(nn) 
m <- betadiver(nn) 
plot(m,col=2) 

## The indices betadiver(help=TRUE) 
## The basic Whittaker index 
d <- betadiver(sipoo, "w") 
## This should be equal to Sorensen index (binary Bray-Curtis in ## vegan) 
range(d - vegdist(nn, binary=TRUE))
```

Pero no se como darle la escala de colores a cada columna, ni como ajustar la escala que convencionalmente viene entre o y 100, y mis valores están entre o y 1.

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y obtener buenas respuestas. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para agregar el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora y eventualmente los problemas con que te has encontrado. Saludos

Comment: Soy nuevo en R, basicamente lo que he realizado es esto:    library (vegan)
library (betapart)
library (ggtern)
## Raw data and plotting
data(nn)
m <- betadiver(nn)
plot(m,col=2)
## The indices
betadiver(help=TRUE)
## The basic Whittaker index
d <- betadiver(sipoo, "w")
## This should be equal to Sorensen index (binary Bray-Curtis in
## vegan)
range(d - vegdist(nn, binary=TRUE))

Comment: Pero no se como darle la escala de colores a cada columna, ni como ajustar la escala que convencionalmente viene entre o y 100, y mis valores están entre o y 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Aclaraciones

Tomo el data.frame de la pregunta como los datos finales a ser gratificados. Dos aclaraciones:

- No sé si sobre esos datos estás aplicando otras transformaciones posteriormente. De todas formas el código debería funcionar siempre que tengas tres columnas con valores que van de 0 a 1.
- En la pregunta dices que es una matriz. Si es así en sentido de R (`is.matrix(x)`) deberías pasarlo primero a data.frame, de lo contrario `ggplot2` y `ggtern` no van a aceptar el input.

## Código

```
    library(tidyverse)   #Para tribble(), puede no ser necesario si ya tienes los datos.
    library(ggtern)      #Para `coord_tern()`
    tribble(~Regiones,       ~βjtu,       ~βjne,     ~βjac,
           "I-II"  ,        0.85,        0.05,      0.90,
           "I-III" ,        0.78,        0.02,      0.80,
           "I-IV"  ,        0.44,        0.24,      0.68,
           "I-V"   ,        0.77,        0.08,      0.85,
           "I-VI"  ,        0.85,        0.02,      0.85,
           "I-VII" ,        0.85,        0.09,      0.81,
           "II-III",        0.88,        0.03,      0.91,
           "II-IV" ,        0.51,        0.32,      0.85,
           "II-V"  ,        0.88,        0.04,      0.89,
           "II-VI" ,        0.88,        0.02,      0.91,
           "II-VII",        0.91,        0.02,      0.91) -> datos_ternarios
```

Con esto dejo preparados los datos.

```
    ggplot(datos_ternarios, aes(x=βjtu, y=βjne, z=βjac, color= Regiones)) + 
    geom_point() +
    coord_tern()
```

Con `color = Regiones` le indico que haga una escala de colores para cada valor único de esa variable. Automáticamente hace la leyenda. También es automático el escalado a 100, aunque tus datos crudos vayan entre 0 y 1.

## Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el gráfico básico con los valores por defecto, puedes ajustar más cosas como las líneas de guía, color del fondo, etc. Te recomiendo visitar http://www.ggtern.com para ver opciones de ajustes. Cuando se usa `coord_tern()` algunas cosas funcionan un poco diferente que en los gráficos de `ggplot` con coordenadas cartesianas.

Cualquier otra duda puedes ponerla en comentarios o actualizar tu pregunta.

> PD: si fueras a usar el gráfico en una publicación el autor de `ggtern` solicita que incluyas el paquete en la bibliografía de tu paper. Considerando que el software que ofrece es libre y que eso podría ayudar a su carrera creo que sería de buen gusto hacerlo. No es obligatorio.

Comment: Me prece bien, si los graficos están previamente tratados con la funcion betapart del vegan, me parece bien pero la idea es graficar los valores de cada columna, independientemente de la leyenda de las regiones, o sea algo como esto:

Comment: library (vegan)
library (betapart)
library (ggtern)

mi xlsx = data.frame(bjtu = runif(100),
                bjne = runif(100),
                bjac = runif(100),
                beta_diversidad = runif(100))

ggtern(data = mi xlsx, aes(x=bjtu, y=bjne, z=bjac)) +
    Tlab('bjtu') +
    Llab('bjne')+
    Rlab(expression(paste(bjac))) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = beta diversidad)) +
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(terrain.colors(100)))

Comment: la cuestion es que va de 0-100, esa ecala no se puede poner a favor de los datos??, porque de otra forma no se ve casi la disperción de los datos para cada componente.

Comment: Para explicarme la idea es hacer un gráfico, con un color para cada región, pero que arriba del  punto esté el valor de cada columna para cada punto.

Comment: Necesito algo com esto, lo tomé de http://www.ggtern.com/ #Variabels
set.seed(1)
n  = 10;   #Number of Data Points
nv = 0.05  #Vertical Adjustment
 
#Define Data
df = data.frame(x     = runif(n),
                y     = runif(n),
                z     = runif(n),
                label = sprintf("L%s",1:n),
                color = factor(sample(1:3,n,replace=TRUE)))

Comment: #Define Position Adjustment for Labels
#Use Nudge instead of vjust (Nudge is better for geom_label)
pn = position_nudge_tern(y=nv,x=-nv/2,z=-nv/2)
 
#Create base plot, and two examples of different labelling techniques
base = ggtern(df,aes(x,y,z,color=color)) + 
       geom_point() +   #Base Geometry
       theme_nomask() + #Allow Labels to Spool Over Edges
       theme_legend_position('topleft')
A = base + 
    geom_text( position=pn,aes(label=label),size=2)
B = base + 
    geom_label(position=pn,aes(label=label),size=2)
 
#Arrange A and B, 1 x 2
grid.arrange(A,B,ncol=2)

Comment: Cuando plote el grafico me queda uno triangular igual al mio, pero necesito que donde diga colo sea Regiones y sea un color para cada par de regiones y dentro del gráfico donde están los cuadros los valores de cada punto según su columna. Me expliqué????. Cçomo se sube una foto para enseñar a que me refiero???

Comment: La forma más fácil es subirla a un servidor de imágenes tipo imgur y poner el enlace. Para que la imagen salga en el post es necesario cierto nivel de reputación, pero de todos modos se puede ver picando en el enlace. Cuando tengas más reputación vas a poder subir imágenes directamente.

Comment: Me podrias ayudar entonces con lo antes expuesto, estoy modificando el código y me da error en la línea pn (no se a que está haciendo referencia):oo = data.frame(bsor =runif(100),
                bsim =runif(100),
                bnes =(100),
                label = sprintf("L%s",1:100),
                color = factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE)))
 
#Define Position Adjustment for Labels
#Use Nudge instead of vjust (Nudge is better for geom_label)
pn = position_nudge_tern(bsor=nv,bsim=-nv/2,bnes=-nv/2)

Comment: En el último código que pusiste `pn` se usa para ubicar las etiquetas, **no** está afectando a la ubicación de los puntos, colores, escalas, etc. De todos modos ya me perdí con respecto a lo que estás preguntando. ¿Podrías reformular la pregunta y poner un ejemplo reproducible con los datos finales que vas a pasar al plot?

Comment: Necesito hacer un grafico triangular. Todos los pares de regiones con un color por ejemplo I-II azul, I-III roja y asi sucesivamente pero que ademas arriba me diga el valor de cada componenete en las otras tres columnas